# Export data generated in JPanel to excel

Tags: java, excel, apache, jpanel

I have a Java Application that creates a JPanel menu and part of the program is to export data provided by the user inside JPanel to excel.

I want to create excel file and provide certain formatting inside my program.

I have tried using Apache POI, my code for the function is below. The function is called with a press of a button inside the JPanel when the application is running.

```
    private static void processExcelInformation() throws FileNotFoundException
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "stuck before workbook", "Display",
            JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); // <---- I cannot seem to initialize new workbook
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "created workbook", "Display",
            JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE); // <---- This message is not displayed when the application runs
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample sheet");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "created sheet", "Display",
            JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

    Map<String, Object[]> data = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();
    data.put("1", new Object[] {"Emp No.", "Name", "Salary"});
    data.put("2", new Object[] {1d, "John", 1500000d});
    data.put("3", new Object[] {2d, "Sam", 800000d});
    data.put("4", new Object[] {3d, "Dean", 700000d});

    Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();
    int rownum = 0;
    for (String key : keyset) {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
        Object [] objArr = data.get(key);
        int cellnum = 0;
        for (Object obj : objArr) { // <---- This statement does not allow the application to run, I get an error
            Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
            if(obj instanceof Date) 
                cell.setCellValue((Date)obj);
            else if(obj instanceof Boolean)
                cell.setCellValue((Boolean)obj);
            else if(obj instanceof String)
                    cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
            else if(obj instanceof Double)
                cell.setCellValue((Double)obj);
        }
    }

    try {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "stuck before xls", "Display",
                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        FileOutputStream out = 
                new FileOutputStream(new File("new.xls"));
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Excel written", "Display",
                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Check for comments where I have issues with my code.

Maybe someone can recommend me another way to complete my task or provide me a solution to my issues.

Thanks

Here's more to my code...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            soccerStock = new ArrayList<Soccer>();
            childrenStock = new ArrayList<Children>();
            miniSoccerStock = new ArrayList<MiniSoccer>();
            tennisStock = new ArrayList<Tennis>();
            universalStock = new ArrayList<Universal>();
            try {
//                  processExcelInformation();
                parseXMLInput();
                initializeGrassChoices();

            } catch (JAXBException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Calculator ex = new Calculator();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

public Calculator() {
    initUI();
}

public final void initUI() {
    initGrassRollChoices();
    initPanel();
    createMenu();   
}
```

This is the button that calls processExcelInformation() function...

```
JMenuItem xls = new JMenuItem("Excel", null);
    xls.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
    xls.setToolTipText("Export Excel");

    xls.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            try {
                processExcelInformation();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });
```

When I call processExcelInformation() during compilation from main function it creates the excel file as asked. However, when I write my code to call processExcelInformation() function using a button I get an error when launching my application.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source package called Jexcel which might provide the tools you need. See this [Source Forge site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jexcelapi/files/) for the source packages. For tutorials and API docs you can [look here](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/).

Additional: I've just read some reviews. Seems JExcel doesn't enjoy a very good rep and doesn't support xlsx format.

Looking at your code I can see that there may be a problem with the for-loop you've indicated. You haven't mentioned what the error is, but I suspect you cannot simply treat an array as a collection. I'd be inclined to try something more traditional like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < objArr.length; i++){
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JExcel](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/). It´s pretty easy to use  if you don´t need overly complicated spreadsheets and there are a lot examples and HowTos if you ask our friend Google.